# Generate sequence of numbers increasing after n rows by group in R data.table

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, sequence

I have a data.table like this:

```
        customer_id account_id       time count
 1:           1        AAA 2000-01-01     0
 2:           1        AAA 2000-02-01     1
 3:           1        AAA 2000-03-01     2
 4:           1        AAA 2000-04-01     3
 5:           1        AAA 2000-05-01     4
 6:           1        AAA 2000-06-01     5
 7:           1        AAA 2000-07-01     6
 8:           1        AAA 2000-08-01     7
 9:           2        BBB 2008-01-01     0
10:           2        BBB 2008-02-01     1
11:           2        BBB 2008-03-01     2
12:           2        BBB 2008-04-01     3
13:           2        BBB 2008-05-01     4
14:           2        BBB 2008-06-01     5
15:           2        BBB 2008-07-01     6
16:           2        BBB 2008-08-01     7
17:           2        BBB 2008-09-01     8
18:           2        BBB 2008-10-01     9
19:           2        BBB 2008-11-01    10
20:           2        BBB 2008-12-01    11
21:           2        BBB 2009-01-01    12
22:           2        BBB 2009-02-01    13
23:           2        BBB 2009-03-01    14
24:           2        BBB 2009-04-01    15
```

The code for creation of this data.table is here:

```
customer_id <- c(rep(1,8), rep(2,16))
account_id <- c(rep("AAA",8), rep("BBB",16))
time <- c(seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 8), 
seq(as.Date("2008/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 16))

count <- c(seq(from = 0, to = 7), seq(from = 0, to = 15))

my_data <- data.table(customer_id,account_id,time,count)
```

I would like to generate a new variable called for example new_var that would be equal to 0 if variable `count` is between 1 and 4, 1 if `count` is between 5 and 8, 2 if `coun`t is between 9 and 12, etc. That is, by `customer_id`, `account_id`, I would like to create a new variable that would start with 1 and increase by 1 after each 4 values of count. It would look like this:

```
        customer_id account_id       time count new_var
 1:           1        AAA 2000-01-01     0      NA
 2:           1        AAA 2000-02-01     1       0
 3:           1        AAA 2000-03-01     2       0
 4:           1        AAA 2000-04-01     3       0
 5:           1        AAA 2000-05-01     4       0
 6:           1        AAA 2000-06-01     5       1
 7:           1        AAA 2000-07-01     6       1
 8:           1        AAA 2000-08-01     7       1
 9:           2        BBB 2008-01-01     0      NA
10:           2        BBB 2008-02-01     1       0
11:           2        BBB 2008-03-01     2       0
12:           2        BBB 2008-04-01     3       0
13:           2        BBB 2008-05-01     4       0
14:           2        BBB 2008-06-01     5       1
15:           2        BBB 2008-07-01     6       1
16:           2        BBB 2008-08-01     7       1
17:           2        BBB 2008-09-01     8       1
18:           2        BBB 2008-10-01     9       2
19:           2        BBB 2008-11-01    10       2
20:           2        BBB 2008-12-01    11       2
21:           2        BBB 2009-01-01    12       2
22:           2        BBB 2009-02-01    13       3
23:           2        BBB 2009-03-01    14       3
24:           2        BBB 2009-04-01    15       3
```

For count equal to 0, this new variable can be for example NA, it does not matter. Is there any way how to make this sequence (0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,...) in this data.table by group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution.  `group_by` your customer_id and then simply use an `ifelse` statement in your `mutate` to generate your new variable.

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>% group_by(customer_id,account_id) %>% mutate(new_var = ifelse(count==0,NA,floor((count-1)/4)))


# A tibble: 24 x 5
# Groups:   customer_id [2], account_id [1]
#   customer_id account_id time       count new_var
#         <dbl> <chr>      <date>     <int>   <dbl>
# 1           1 AAA        2000-01-01     0      NA
# 2           1 AAA        2000-02-01     1       0
# 3           1 AAA        2000-03-01     2       0
# 4           1 AAA        2000-04-01     3       0
# 5           1 AAA        2000-05-01     4       0
# 6           1 AAA        2000-06-01     5       1
# 7           1 AAA        2000-07-01     6       1
# 8           1 AAA        2000-08-01     7       1
# 9           2 BBB        2008-01-01     0      NA
#10           2 BBB        2008-02-01     1       0
# ... with 14 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution purely in 'data.table' syntax:

```
my_data[, new_var:=ifelse(count==0, NA, floor((count-1)/4)), by=.(customer_id, account_id)]
```